# JSONCPP Writing to files

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

JSONCPP has a writer, but all it seems to do is get info from the parser and then output it into a string or a stream. How do I make it alter or create new objects, arrays, values, strings, et cetera and write them into the file?

Answer (score 52):

```
#include<json/writer.h>
```

Code:

```
    Json::Value event;   
    Json::Value vec(Json::arrayValue);
    vec.append(Json::Value(1));
    vec.append(Json::Value(2));
    vec.append(Json::Value(3));

    event["competitors"]["home"]["name"] = "Liverpool";
    event["competitors"]["away"]["code"] = 89223;
    event["competitors"]["away"]["name"] = "Aston Villa";
    event["competitors"]["away"]["code"]=vec;

    std::cout << event << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
{
        "competitors" : 
        {
                "away" : 
                {
                        "code" : [ 1, 2, 3 ],
                        "name" : "Aston Villa"
                },
                "home" : 
                {
                        "name" : "Liverpool"
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: This looks really nice. What about adding classes, instead of int, with the .append method?

Comment: Thank you. This example was enough to get me started. I don't need the complicated case of writing classes.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <json.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void main()
{
    std::ofstream file_id;
    op_file_id.open("file.txt");

    Json::Value value_obj;
    //populate 'value_obj' with the objects, arrays etc.

    Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;
    file_id << styledWriter.write(value_obj);

    file_id.close();
}
```

Comment: It's easier to understand if you explain your answer and not just post code.

Comment: Class 'styledWriter' is deprecated: Use StreamWriterBuilder instead

Answer (score 10):

AFAICT, you create objects of type Json::Value, which caters for all the JSON data-types, and pass the result to a Json::Writer (one of its derived types, to be specific), or simply to a stream.

E.g.: to write an array of three integers to a file:

```
Json::Value vec(Json::arrayValue);
vec.append(Json::Value(1));
vec.append(Json::Value(2));
vec.append(Json::Value(3));
std::cout << vec;
```

Comment: But I want to write it to the .json file.

Comment: Then use an `ofstream` instead of `cout`.

Comment: Yelnats, then pipe it to a file instead of std::cout.

Answer (score 9):

`Json::StyledWriter` is deprecated, you can use `Json::StreamWriterBuilder` to write json into files.

```
Json::Value rootJsonValue;
rootJsonValue["foo"] = "bar";

Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
builder["commentStyle"] = "None";
builder["indentation"] = "   ";

std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter());
std::ofstream outputFileStream("/tmp/test.json");
writer -> write(rootJsonValue, &outputFileStream);
```

The json will be written into `/tmp/test.json`.

```
$ cat /tmp/test.json

{
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to create the desired [`JSON::Value`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html).  You should look at all the constructors ([first](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#da6ba1369448fb0240bccc36efaa46f7)).  To create the necessary hierarchies, see [`append`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#7e49ac977e4bcf59745a09d426669f75) and the operator[] overloads; there are overloads for both array [indices](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#fe163a93dc00a1b5f26b036795f490f8) and [string keys](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#e511c7d46bf457412fb55c9471af9f50) for objects.

<s>One way to write the JSON value back out is using [`StyledStreamWriter::write`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_styled_stream_writer.html#07807741c6c43ecd35885a87234d0805) and [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/).</s>

See cegprakash's answer for how to write it.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this after I read Marcelo's answer. It works.

Comment: `StyledStreamWriter` is deprecated. If you need customization, use [`StreamWriterBuilder`](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_stream_writer_builder.html). Or simply follow the other answers here.